# Data is not getting inserted in mysql through php

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to insert 1 element into a table(It contains 3 columns).

code:

```
<?php
require 'connect.db.php';

$msg = 'msg';
mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages('Message') VALUES ('$msg')");
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER by Msg_ID DESC");
while ($extract = mysql_fetch_array(result1)) {
  echo $extract['Message'];
}


 ?>
```

When i run it I am getting this error:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant result1 - assumed 'result1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\SocialNetwork\chat\chat.php on line 7
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SocialNetwork\chat\chat.php on line 70

Data is not getting inserted to the db..

Error after using mysqli (replaced mysql):

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SocialNetwork\chat\chat.php on line 6
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SocialNetwork\chat\chat.php on line 7
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant result1 - assumed 'result1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\SocialNetwork\chat\chat.php on line 8
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SocialNetwork\chat\chat.php on line 8

Comment: Use mysqli mysql is deprecated and removed from PHP 7

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! ***SQL Injection!*** *It's not just for breakfast any more!*

Comment: The error is obvious here `(result1)` then your column name, well that's the wrong identifier qualifier.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array(result1)` should be `mysql_fetch_array($result1)`

Comment: This question contains so many (syntax) errors, it's NOT funny.

Comment: Your most recent edit made this into another question entirely. Please do not edit posts to make them a different question, ask another ***only after you have researched any new errors***.

Comment: I knw it's not safe.. I was just trying to insert data fr testing @JayBlanchard

Comment: I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."* or *"Security isn't important now..."* or *"Ignore the security risk..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I did. It seems like it's not just that dupe.

Comment: @JayBlanchard ^^^ Agree with you whole heartedly.

Comment: Who upvoted the question?

Comment: Sure wasn't me @JayBlanchard *"mais, au contraire mon frère"* ;-)

Comment: Trueeeeeeeeeee.. I am sorry :( @JayBlanchard .. Going to update code now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong quotes. Use back-ticks `` ` `` for column names:

```sql
INSERT INTO messages(`Message`) VALUES ('$msg')
-- ------------------^-------^
```

**Note:** `mysql_*` is deprecated. Use either `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Also, for the other error, you forgot to add a `$`:

```
while ($extract = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
```

Okay, so now you switched to `mysqli_` function, it is a different story here:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

// And change all the functions to:
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ...");
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT ...");
```

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't explain `Notice: Use of undefined constant result1 - assumed 'result1'` - which is here `mysql_fetch_array(result1)` <<<

Comment: Wait let me try using mysqli or pdo

Comment: No problem, but we have another problem here `mysql_fetch_array()` is for SELECT, not for INSERT ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- There's only `SELECT` there. Check it out.

Comment: I noticed they added that "after" I commented. Big rabbit hole here.

Comment: Aye the problem fixed... Accidentally omitted the $.. But what about those warnings :(

Comment: Who reopened the question?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I did. It seems like it's not just that dupe.

Comment: @PraveenKumar .. Data succesfully inserted.. But it's not printing anything :(

Comment: @IamNOOB Can you update the question with the current code you are using?

Comment: Update or new quesstion ?

Comment: @PraveenKumar .. No problem now I ffixed it B)

Comment: @IamNOOB What was the issue?

Comment: It was not printing anything.. Just bunch of warnings... Now i fixed